# How to take outer td data when the td has inner table JSoup

Tags: html, jsoup

I am using JSoup for web scraping. I have a table with classname `.chart` which has rows (tr) and the rows have data (td). But some of the tds have tables inside which also contain rows and tds. This is the form of one of these problematic tds:

```
<td align="center" onmouseout="hideAlt(104692)" onmouseover="showAlt(104692)">
21
<div id="as104692" class="altsrc" style="height: 32px; top: 308px; left: 622px; display: none;">
<b>Alt Src Locations</b>
<br>
<table class="none" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Lisac's Tire Butte</td>
<td align="right">21</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And this is how I take the data:

```
Elements e = manuf.select("table.chart tr");
            for(Element el : e) {
                Elements columns = el.select("td");
                for(Element c : columns) {
                    System.out.print(c.text() + ", ");
                }
}
```

And this is the result that I get: 21 Alt Src Locations Lisac's Tire Butte 21
And this is the result that I want: 21

How can I tell the program to take only the first td and not get those inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a combination of `ownText()` and an `immediate child` selector

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String html = "<table class=\"chart\">" +
                          "<tr>" +
                          "<td align=\"center\" onmouseout=\"hideAlt(104692)\" onmouseover=\"showAlt(104692)\">" +
                          "21" +
                          "<div id=\"as104692\" class=\"altsrc\" style=\"height: 32px; top: 308px; left: 622px; display: none;\">" +
                          "<b>Alt Src Locations</b>" +
                          "<br>" +
                          "<table class=\"none\" border=\"0\">" +
                          "<tbody>" +
                          "<tr>" +
                          "<td>Lisac's Tire Butte</td>" +
                          "<td align=\"right\">21</td>" +
                          "</tr>" +
                          "</tbody>" +
                          "</table>" +
                          "</div>" +
                          "</td>" +
                          "</tr>" +
                          "</table>";

            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

            Elements els = doc.select("table.chart>tbody>tr>td");
            for(Element el: els) 
                System.out.println(el.ownText());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the >tbody> is implicit, since the code works (it prints the text of the first <td>),  although there is no explicit <tbody> tag in that part of the tree.

Comment: Actually there is. Jsoup's html parser (default) will add missing tags or remove invalid ones so the resulting dom it creates, comforts to html specs. Try printing the `doc` variable of my example and you will see it.